# How to map a stream of class objects into a stream of properties of said class?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class that has 3 properties, all with the same data type, let's say:

```
Class Test {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
}
```

Then, I have a stream containing test classes (assume all the properties are notnull random integers):

```
Stream<Test> originalStream = Stream.of(test1,test2,test3);
```

How can I convert (or map?) that stream to a stream, made up by integers of the class.
Printing now the stream would look like this (printing is not the point, I just used it to illustrate how it should be structured):

`{test1,test2,test3}`

But what I want is for it to look like this:

`{test1.i, test1.j, test1.k, test2.i, test2.j, test2.k, test3.i, test3.j, test3.k}`

I know I probably didn't use the correct terminology (instance, object etc.), but I hope my question is clear.

Comment: can you show the code what you have and what you are expecting ?

Comment: I'll add a pseudo example

Comment: Do you mean `map`?

Comment: Yeah, probably. Yesterday I didn't even know what streams are, so my knowledge is limited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java streams have a powerful method called [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)), which lets you map each element in the stream to another stream, and then returns all of the streams joined together.  So it does exactly what you're asking for, all in one method.  In your particular case, you are using integers, so they even have a specific method for this case called [`flatMapToInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt(java.util.function.Function)), which allows you to use a stream of primitive integer values, rather than their [boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) equivalents.  Here's a simple one-liner using your given example:

```java
IntStream expandedStream = originalStream.flatMapToInt((t) -> IntStream.of(t.i, t.j, t.k));
```

This just turns each element (named `t` here) into an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) containing `t.i`, `t.j`, and `t.k`.  When the method returns, it returns a stream that is made up of all of those 3 element streams combined.

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect for me! Also, thanks for explaining, it seems to me I will use this more

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you're looking for...

```
package streams;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class IntegersToStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        (new IntegersToStream()).run();
    }

    public void run() {

        Test test = new Test(1, 2, 3);

        List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>();
        tests.add(test);

        IntStream intStream = tests.stream()
                .flatMapToInt(t -> IntStream.of(t.getI(), t.getJ(), t.getK()));

        intStream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public class Test {

        int i;
        int j;
        int k;

        public Test(int i, int j, int k) {

            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
            this.k = k;
        }

        public int getI() {
            return i;
        }

        public int getJ() {
            return j;
        }

        public int getK() {
            return k;
        }
    }
}
```

Output...

```
1
2
3
```